# Is it possible to modify an ASM's MethodVisitor object using Byte Buddy's high level API?

Tags: byte-buddy

I'm currently trying to learn how to create Kotlin Compiler Plugins for the JVM and I'd like to change a method's body as an example, the API requires to manipulate Java byte code using ASM API in order to make any changes to a class' components. The Kotlin compiler plugin provides [this class](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/compiler/backend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/codegen/ClassBuilder.java) where, if for example, you'd like to modify a class' method body, you'd need to override the `newMethod` function, which returns a `MethodVisitor` instance, which is the one that you'd need to manually modify using the ASM's API.

I would like to be able of doing so without having to write ASM instructions and I was wondering if there was a way to add instructions straight into a `MethodVisitor` object using Byte Buddy's high level API?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite honestly, the API is a bit awkward since it does not follow the standard model of ASM where you wrap a class visitor and since it shades the ASM dependency which makes it non-compatible with any ASM user.

In Byte Buddy, you can register your own visitors so what you can do is to define a custom class in Byte Buddy, and before calling `make`, you'd register an `AsmVisitorWrapper` which delegates to the visitor Kotlin yields. You'd need to proxy all method calls from Kotlin's ASM namespace to Byte Buddy's ASM namespace, though what you can do using method handles.

Comment: I see, yeah the API seems to have room for improvement. I kinda found a way by compiling the class using Kotlin's API and then using the compiled class to create a Byte Buddy instance from it, the only downside though is that this compilation API that Kotlin provides, doesn't provide a ClassLoader but just a single class at a time, therefore if one class extends another, even from the same project, the Byte Buddy instance fails to get created since it doesn't find the linked classes. Anyway, I think it's mostly due to the Kotlin API limitations, I just wanted to confirm if there was a way 